# Available Options for HTML Static File Templating

Tags: html, css, templates, static

What are the most common options for templating HTML files for static pages, to minimize maintenance and redundancy? An example of my question would be Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: Is your site just a bunch of separate .html files? What tools are you using to create the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a server-side scripting language such as PHP or ASP.NET.  These produce dynamically built web-pages meaning that you can code it in such a way that headers/footers etc are separate from the main content, meaning you change that link once rather than 30 times.

If server-side scripting is not an option, I'd suggest having a look at Dreamweaver.  This will enable you to create templates, and then create pages based on those templates.  When you modify that link in the template, all pages that use that template will be updated.  This will give you what you want without the server-side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use iframe inside ? ( which will contain a single navigation html page...)?

Comment: OK, and why not AJAX instead of iframe?

Comment: @suddenly_me, an IFrame is a bad way to go about solving his problem.  Using an IFrame would mean that, as the page changes, the user would not be able to bookmark the page they are viewing (because the main page is at the same URL).  I also have no idea how AJAX comes in to this :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice you didnt understand me... I said that only the navigation will be in iframe and each link will change the ADDRESS URL to the real address - so it can be bookmarked. and the new page will also have the iframe to be pressed.....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a server-side language like PHP, you can start to use the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function. So you'll include in a different file your navigation bar and then include it in every file of your website. Thus, every change to the navigation bar file will affect all the  others files.

If you are writing only static pages, it isn't possible. Maybe you can try [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need either a fancy program (like Dreamweaver and its templates functionality) or some sort of server-side scripting.  Languages like php, asp, etc might be a bit much if the only thing you are looking to do is as you describe, so I might look into seeing if your server support server side includes (SSI).